# Show and then hide a Bootstrap Alert while JQuery runs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-deferred

When a user changes a dropdown on my page, I have some JQuery that does "stuff". I want to add the "show" class to my Bootstrap alert and then remove it when "stuff" is done. In my current attempt, I use a `Deferred.done()` method but it doesn't seem to work as I intend. The `addClass` and `removeClass` functions are both run before the DOM refreshes so the alert is never seen. Any tips?

Code:

```
$(".my-dropdown").change(function() {
    var show_alert = function() {
        var r = $.Deferred();
        $('#update-alert').addClass("show");
        return r;
    }

    var updategraph = function() {
        "stuff"
        $('#update-alert').removeClass("show");
    }

    show_alert().done(updategraph());
})
```

Comment: What is **"stuff"**? If it's an **async** function, then you should restructure your code.

Comment: It's a call to a d3.js function which empties the SVG and then re-runs my render function. I'll be honest I'm not too familiar with what async functions are past surface level knowledge

Comment: Does the function really finish that fast? I mean: does your alert have time to appear (if it would work as you want it to work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```js
// setting up a function to wrap the removeClass() in a
// setTimeout() function
const removeShowClass = () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#alert').removeClass('show')
  }, 2000)
}

// simulating a "quick" process
jQuery('#quick').on('click', function(e) {
  jQuery('#alert').addClass('show')
  removeShowClass()
})

// simulating a "slow" process
jQuery('#slow').on('click', function(e) {
  jQuery('#alert').addClass('show')
  setTimeout(function() {
    removeShowClass()
  }, 2000)
})
```

```css
.alert:not( .show) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.alert.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="alert" class="alert">ALERT</div>
<br />
<br />
<button id="quick">QUICK PROCESS ALERT</button>
<br />
<br />
<button id="slow">SLOW PROCESS ALERT</button>
```

If you just call the `removeClass()` in a simple `setTimeout()`, then the alerts will surely show up - they will disappear after the process is finished + set amount in milliseconds. This way you can make sure that the `alert` is displayed minimum for the time set in the `setTimeout()`.